# Push / pop a cmake variable

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to temporarily alter a CMake variable while executing another `CMakeLists.txt` file. Something like this?

```
PUSH ( SOME_VARIABLE )
SET ( SOME_VARIABLE "temporary value" )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( "subdir" )
POP ( SOME_VARIABLE )
```

I know you can do it like this:

```
SET ( SOME_VARIABLE_TMP "${SOME_VARIABLE}" )
SET ( SOME_VARIABLE "temporary value" )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( "subdir" )
SET ( SOME_VARIABLE "${SOME_VARIABLE_TMP} )
```

And I guess I could even make some hacky functions to do it myself, something like this (untested):

```
FUNCTION ( PUSH VARNAME )
    SET ( ${VARNAME}_TMP "${${VARNAME}}" PARENT_SCOPE )
ENDFUNCTION ()

FUNCTION ( POP VARNAME )
    SET ( ${VARNAME} "${${VARNAME}_TMP}" PARENT_SCOPE )
ENDFUNCTION ()
```

You could maybe even extend that so it works if you do push push pop pop. But I want to know **is there a nice way to do it natively**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't a nice way to do it natively.

You could just move the `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY()` and all variable modifications into a `FUNCTION()` itself. That would give you your own variable scope:

```
FUNCTION( ADD_MY_SUBDIR )
    SET ( SOME_VARIABLE "temporary value" )
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( "subdir" )
ENDFUNCTION ()
```